# Cannot load XLS transformer. Please make sure a Transformer implementation is in classpath

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, maven, jar

Good Morning, 
I'm trying to replicate this: http://jxls.sourceforge.net/getting_started.html

Using my own class action instead of employees.
But I have some issue.

This is my code:

```
package src;

import java.util.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;


import org.jxls.common.Context;
import org.jxls.util.JxlsHelper;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;



public class Excel {

public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException, InterruptedException{

    String srcFilePath  = "C:/Users/BKLYN/workspace/GenerateABSValues/action_template.xls";
    String destFilePath = "C:/Users/BKLYN/workspace/GenerateABSValues/actionCour.xls";

    LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Excel.class);
    logger.info("Test Action");

    //List<action> listAction = generateData(time);


    try(InputStream is = Excel.class.getResourceAsStream(srcFilePath)) {
        try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destFilePath)) {
            List<action> listAction = generateData(time);
            Context context = new Context();
            context.putVar("action", listAction);
            JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(is, os, context);
            System.out.println("5");

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}



    private static List<action> generateData(LocalTime time){

        List<action> listAction = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i =0; i<10; i++){
            listAction.add(new action("AB SCIENCE", time, i));
            System.out.println("name=" + "AB SCIENCE" + " time= " + time + " Value= " + i);
        }
        return listAction;
    }


 }
```

I generate values for action which is the employees of the tutorial.

I add theses jar files to my project: 
asm-3.3.1.jar -
cglib-2.2.2.jar -
commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar - 
commons-codec-1.9.jar -
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar -
commons-digester3-3.2-with-deps.jar -
commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar -
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar -
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar -
jxl-2.6.10.jar -
log4j-1.2.14.jar -
logback-classic-1.1.3.jar - 
logback-core-1.1.3.jar - 
poi-3.12.jar - 
poi-ooxml-3.12.jar -
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12.jar - 
slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar - 
stax-api-1.0.1.jar - 
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar -
jxls-2.3.0.jar - 
jxls-jexcel-1.0.6.jar - 
jxls-poi-1.0.9.jar - 
jxls-reader-2.0.2.jar  -

And when I try to run the project I got this:

```
19:38:14.601 [main] DEBUG org.jxls.util.TransformerFactory - Transformer class is org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer
19:38:14.608 [main] ERROR org.jxls.util.TransformerFactory - Method createTransformer of org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer class thrown an Exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~   [na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.jxls.util.TransformerFactory.createTransformer(TransformerFactory.java:35) ~[jxls-2.3.0.jar:na]
at org.jxls.util.JxlsHelper.createTransformer(JxlsHelper.java:202) [jxls-2.3.0.jar:na]
at org.jxls.util.JxlsHelper.processTemplate(JxlsHelper.java:93) [jxls-2.3.0.jar:na]
at src.Excel.main(Excel.java:43) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:162) ~[poi-ooxml-3.12.jar:3.12]
at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:143) ~[poi-ooxml-3.12.jar:3.12]
at org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer.createTransformer(PoiTransformer.java:49) ~[jxls-poi-1.0.9.jar:na]
at org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer.createTransformer(PoiTransformer.java:42) ~[jxls-poi-1.0.9.jar:na]
... 8 common frames omitted


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load XLS transformer. Please make  sure a Transformer implementation is in classpath
at org.jxls.util.JxlsHelper.createTransformer(JxlsHelper.java:204)
at org.jxls.util.JxlsHelper.processTemplate(JxlsHelper.java:93)
at src.Excel.main(Excel.java:43)
```

And the dependencies I have now:

```
 <dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls-poi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.9</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jxls-jexcel</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I tried to add many different things to the depencies, nothing changed. I updated the project with maven > update project. It was worst. I recreated the project different times to add correctly the jar to avoid conflict. I know that other people already asked for this but I couldn't find a correct answer.

I'm not really good at using java so maybe the error is  obvious. What is the missing file and where/how could I add it ?

Thank you.

Comment: You are misusing the `getResourceAsStream` method.  It does not open files and it does not expect a file name as an argument.  The value of srcFilePath is not a valid resource path, so it is returning null.  Use `Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(srcFilePath))` or `new FileInputStream(srcFilePath)` instead.

Comment: Thank you now it's working correctly !!

Answer (score 1):

If you use maven, maven can break excel file while building.

Exceptions reported by JXLS can be ambiguous,it's actually creating an excel file exception.

You can do like this:

```
 <resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>template/*.*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>template/*.*</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
 </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried a lot and solved the issues but adding the below List of dependency JAR used to solve this issue

commons-codec-1.10.jar
commons-collections4-4.1.jar
commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
jxls-2.4.0.jar
jxls-jexcel-1.0.6.jar
jxls-poi-1.0.12.jar
jxls-reader-2.0.2.jar
poi-3.14.jar
poi-ooxml-3.15.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar